# Assign a path to a variable using Sed filter

Tags: linux, sed, command

Our repositories data directory path is looks like  **/srv/git/repositories/group/subgroup/project.git** and I would like to get path name after **repositories** and assign it to a variable. I have tried below command didn't giving me any output. The path name before and after **repositories** changes so I didn't give absolute path in sed filter

pwd = srv/git/repositories/ group/subgroup/project.git  [look a like]

```
RW_DIR=$(echo $pwd | sed 's/.*/repositories/\(*\).*/\1/')
```

Expecting output

**RW_DIR=group/subgroup/project**        [just project name not project.git]

Can anyone please help in getting the output.

I appreciate everyone's help

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ echo '/srv/git/repositories/group/subgroup/project.git' |
    sed -E 's|.*repositories/(.*)\.git$|\1|'
```

or

```
$ echo '/srv/git/repositories/group/subgroup/project.git' |
    sed -E 's|.*repositories/||; s|\.git$||'
```

or

```
$ echo '/srv/git/repositories/group/subgroup/project.git' |
    grep -oP 'repositories/\K.*(?=\.git)'
```

or if the number of subdirs are fixed :

```
$ echo '/srv/git/repositories/group/subgroup/project.git' |
    awk -F'[./]' 'BEGIN{OFS="/"}{print $5,$6,$7}'
```

### Output :

```
group/subgroup/project
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much Sir